# Selenium fails logging in to Facebook

Tags: python, facebook, selenium

When I try to log in to Facebook using Selenium on Python I'm receiving [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6J3P.png).

What can I do to solve this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow! Please have a look on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, and please provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Moreover it would be easier for us to help you if you post the code that is giving you problem.

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Chrome WebDriver you can try to disable notifications by adding Chrome Options:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```